# Is there a way to load specific assets in Rails for individual views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, load, view, assets, pipeline

What I mean when I ask this is, "Is there a way that an individual view can load w/ specific stylesheets and resources?".
Now, I'm not referring to the classic usages of script and link HTML tags to reference resources, primarily because when Rails loads, it precompiles ALL of the available assets provided.
The main reason I want to do this is because after a while I find that there are so many good web development frameworks out there that it can be very fun to mix and match various ones, and it's really hard to target one framework to use all the time. Also, there can usually be a lot of conflict between various frameworks because of like naming systems (e.g. Bootstrap 2 alongside Bootstrap 3).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand ok, you can do the following:

Application layout:

```
yield :stylesheets if content_for? :stylesheets
```

In specific view:

```
content_for :stylesheet do
 = stylesheet_link_tag "specific_style"
```

Make sure to precompile "specific_style" in `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile << ['application.css', 'specific_style.css']
```

Comment: The `stylesheet_link_tag` is basically nothing but a basic link tag. Essentially this does nothing, because everything still gets compiled all together. Particularly if Sprockets is kept in the Rails app and the "require tree" statement is set in the application.css.

Comment: did you restart your rails application after changing application.rb? because that should make `specific_style.css` available as its own asset - however if you are still doing require_tree in application.css it will include the contents of specific_style (but the precompile in application will create the separate asset as well) - consider not using require_tree and be specific about what you include - the above answer is correct